# How to get the min/max values in a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, max, min

I have a list of arrays:

```
m=[ [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1] , [5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7] , [10, 12, 10, 12, 11, 11] , [8, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9] , [6, 5, 10, 12, 15, 19]]
```

I need to get the max or min of each array in the list. Can you help me please?

Comment: Use a list comprehension  `[max(i) for i in m]`

Comment: There's a `min()` function, a `max()` function, and there are loops and things called "list comprehensions".

Comment: *get max or min* - what exactly?

Comment: i need index of each max or min value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the min or the max:

```
>>> map(min, m)
[1, 5, 10, 5, 5]
>>> map(max, m)
[6, 8, 12, 10, 19]
```

If you need both:

```
>>> [(min(a), max(a)) for a in m]
[(1, 6), (5, 8), (10, 12), (5, 10), (5, 19)]
```

Comment: I prefer list comprehensions. :) `[(min(a), max(a)) for a in m]`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with them. Here is a simple version, you can format it better to suit your needs.

```
for i in m:
   print('Max: ' + str(max(i)))
   print('Min: ' + str(min(i)))
```